# How to get a td in a table exists in a div from the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table inside a div. Each `td` in the table has a class.

I want to get a `td` from the `div`.

I though that children function could get the `td` but seems it does not.

```
var parentDiv = $(".divClass");

parentDiv.each(function (index) {
               var childTd = $(this).children(".tdClass");
```

Any help!

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you want to use simple query. The jQuery was designed for things like this:))

```
var tdArray=$(".divClass .tdClass")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to traverse through all the td's. You need something like this.

```
$(".divClass table tbody tr td ").each(function (i,ele){


    }
```

Only td with a particular class

```
  $(".divClass .tdClass).each(function (i,ele){


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use, the find method of jQuery:

`$("#.divClass").find('td')` or `$("#.divClass").children('td')`

or in a normal table

```
$("#.divClass").find('tr').children('td').
```

What I'm using is appending rows in a table.

I'm using

```
$("#.divClass").find('tbody').append($('<tr>')
                        .append($('<td>')
                                .text("testdata")
                        )
```

.......

Answer (score 0):

to get all the td you can do :

```
$(".divClass > td.className ").each(function (i,ele){


}
```

to access a specific td then,

```
$(".divClass > td.className ").eq(0);
```

[this](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) might help you